# Exception Description: An incompatible mapping has been encountered between [class Entidades.Pais] and [class Entidades.Provincia]

Tags: java, eclipselink

This is the class Provincia with their attributes and I want to make a relationship ManyToOne with the class Pais (a Pais has many Provincia)

```
public class Provincia implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idProvincia")
    private Collection<Localidad> localidadCollection;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @NotNull
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="Pais_ID", referencedColumnName = "Pais_ID")
    private Pais idPais;
}
```

Now the class Pais and their attributes

```
public class Pais implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idPais")
    private Collection<Provincia> provinciaCollection;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Nombre")
    private String nombre;
}
```

Someone who can help me. I'm work in NetBeans 7.3 and with EclipseLink..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to change as below

```
@JoinColumn(name="Pais_ID", referencedColumnName = "Id")
private Pais idPais;
```

Comment: thanks for the help but it's not the solution..i will continue investigating